# ODP.NET - Connection Pool not filling

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

.NET web application connecting to an Oracle 12c database with a 12c client / ODP.NET.

On most machines, it works fine. We have some pages where we wind up with 2 connections to the same database - I know this is not good practice, but that's how it is coded and it works on most machines and it isn't going to be changed at this point.

On a few machines, these pages with the nested connections fail - we get connection timeouts with no ORA- code and a -1000 error code in the code that opens the 2nd connection. Even if we set a minimum on the connection pool, it just stays at 1. The connections are timing out seemingly without even attempting to actually connect to the database. The symptoms look similar to what is described in this unanswered question from 2017, although our problem is not intermittent - happens every time on the affected machines: [ODP.NET Connection request timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43295135/odp-net-connection-request-timed-out])

On the machines where this is failing, if we turn off connection pooling in the connection string, then the problem pages work, but much too slowly - response time is minutes.

Clearly something is different about the configuration on the problem machines, but I haven't been able to find what. Many hours comparing the machines and scouring the internet and still haven't figured this out.

I think this may have something to do with distributed transactions, but I haven't yet found the setting that will fix it. Has anyone seen this and have any ideas on where the problem may be?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not an answer but a work-around. Instead of using a TNS identifier, I put the connection information directly into the connection string, and it suddenly started working.

I took a better trace than I had before and noticed a bunch of "cannot resolve TNS" in the trace in addition to the connection timeout errors.